# Set sorting of MatSort in code after proxy call results in ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting

I want to keep the sorting settings of my table after reloading the data. I try to do this by triggering the sorting in code after calling the proxy:

```
this.keptSort = 'name',
this.keptSortDirection = 'desc',
this.someProxy
    .getTableContent(this.id)            
        .subscribe((res) => {
            const rows = res.map((r) => new RowMode(r)); 
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(rows);
            this.selectRowsWithId(this.selection);
            if (this.sort) {
                this.sort.sort(<MatSortable>{ 
                   id: this.keptSort, 
                   start: this.keptSortDirection});
            }
});
```

My table in html is as such:

```
<table
    mat-table                    
    matSort
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    matSortActive="creationDate"
    matSortDirection="desc" >
...</table>
```

This however results in an error:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'active: undefined'. Current value: 'active: false'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked.

Extra info, I also have a MatSort setter as such:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    if (ms) {
        this.sort = ms;
        this.setDataSourceAttributes();
    }
}
```

and

```
setDataSourceAttributes() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;        
}
```

Any ideas or direction pointers on  how I can fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a workaround! :D

For those who are interested:

I removed the 'if (this.sort) { ... }' part from the subscribe of my proxy.

Then I changed my table html, now using functions to define the sorting:

```
<table
    mat-table                    
    matSort
    [dataSource]="dataSource"
    [matSortActive]="getActiveSort()"
    [matSortDirection]="getSortDirection()" >
...</table>
```

And these functions return the required sorting settings.

Comment: I can confirm this solution fixed the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error for me too, switched from trying to assign it via the component logic. Just wanted to add that I'm using Observables and was able to use the async pipe to pass it into the template.

Comment: Works - and saved me lots of more headaches!

Instead of calling functions I use fields, though.